# reload after a unwind to viewController in swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3, unwind-segue

I have put in `TableViewControler` (my third page) a table to select a variable and next unwind to a `ViewController` and reload it with the new value but I tried to search about but I didn't found the answer. I'm working with swift 3 please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately swift doesn't have a method to reload a view after it's already loaded. When you push your TableView, the former ViewController remains loaded in the background. 
you can add the following code to any ViewController to see when it load and when it deallocate.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    print("init controller")
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

deinit {
    print("deinit controller")
}
```

Now I don't know how your code works in the ViewController but im guessing you're using `viewDidLoad()` to set it up in the first place. In that case you can try including the code you use to setup the ViewController in `func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` to reload the view when it reappears.

If you can provide your code I might be able to provide you with a better answer.